# Topology such that a sequence converges to $x_0$ iff $x_0$ appears in it infinitely many times

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence

Let $X$ be an uncountable set.

Does there exist a topology $\mathcal{T}$ on $X$ with the property that a sequence $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ in $X$ converges to $x_0 \in X$ if and only if $x_0$ appears in the sequence infinitely many times?

---

My attempt:

Assume such a topology $\mathcal{T}$ exists. Let $x_0, x, y \in X$ be three different points. The sequence $(x_0, x, x_0, x, \ldots)$ converges only to $x_0$ and $x$ so the set $\{x_0, x\}$ must be in $\mathcal{T}.$ Similarly we show that $\{x_0, y\} \in \mathcal{T}$. Thus
$$\{x_0\} = \{x_0, x\} \cap \{x_0, y\} \in \mathcal{T}$$

Hence, it must be $\mathcal{T} = \mathcal{P}(X)$. But then the sequence $(x_0, x, x_0, x, \ldots)$ cannot converge to $x_0$ as there does not exist $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n \geq n_0 \implies x_n \in \{x_0\}$. This is a contradiction so such a topology cannot exist.

Is this approach correct?

Comment: @MJD $x_0$ and $x$ both appear in it infinitely many times. $x_0$ is an arbitrary point in $X$, not a fixed one.

Comment: What is your argument that $\{x_0,x\}$ should be open?

Comment: Maybe you meant that $\{ x_0, x \}$ should be closed, i.e. the complement of $\{ x_0, x \}$ is in $\mathcal{T}$?  But that doesn't really follow either, since if $\mathcal{T}$ doesn't happen to be first-countable, then limits of sequences don't necessarily characterize the full closure.

Comment: @DanielSchepler It was just a mistake. All I had was that $\{x_0, x\}$ is contained in every neighbourhood of $x_0$.

Comment: What if $X=\{x_0,x,y\}$ and $T=\{\phi, \{y\},X\} $?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Then the sequence $(x_0, y, x_0, y, \ldots)$ would not converge to $y$.

Comment: My point is that $\{x,x_0\}\not \in T$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see how you would deduce that $\{x_0,x\} \in \mathcal{T}$. What I see how to deduce is that then *every* neighbourhood of $x_0$ must contain $x$. For the neighbourhood $U$ of $x_0$ contains the terms of the sequence, except possibly for finitely many indices. But since every term of the sequence is repeated infinitely many times, every term of the sequence lies in $U$. Since $x$ was arbitrary, it follows that the only neighbourhood of $x_0$ is the whole space $X$.

Thus a topology in which "occurring infinitely often in a sequence" is sufficient for that sequence to converge to the infinitely often occurring point is necessarily indiscrete.

But in an indiscrete space, every sequence converges to every point, so if $X$ contains more than one point, no topology in which a sequence converges to $x_0$ if and only if $x_0$ occurs infinitely often in the sequence exists.

Comment: Thanks. I just had $\{x_0, x\} \subseteq U$, for every open neighbourhood of $x_0$. It was a mistake to deduce that $\{x_0, x\}$ is open.